# Unknown Build Error 'key cannot be null'

Tags: xaml

I have a data template for my listbox and I must use project resources for all the labels. If I remove the reference to the resource and just type in the text for the labels there are no errors. If I try to use the resources I get the above error.

Here is the data template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxDatePickerItemTemplate">
    <Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3" BorderBrush="{StaticResource GreenBorderBrush}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#208897EB" MinWidth="370">
            <CheckBox Focusable="False" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Name, Mode=OneTime}" Margin="2,2" Width="140" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Visibility="{Binding DateDataVisible}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IncludeNullDates}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Focusable="False"/>
                    <Label Content="{x:Static resx:Resources.Label_IncludeEmptyDates}" Margin="2,2" Width="170" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{x:Static resx:Resources.Label_From}" Margin="2,0" Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding StartDate}" Margin="2,2" Width="150" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{x:Static resx:Resources.Label_To}" Margin="2,0" Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding EndDate}" Margin="2,2" Width="150" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

One thing to note we are using the resources in other XAML files with no problems. This file however is a resource dictionary and is added to the app.xaml resources. What's with this error?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

We are working on this project in a team and I just copied the line for using resources... I just forgot to copy the xmlns attribute as well. What I find strange is that the error isn't really descriptive and doesn't give any real hints as to what the problem is.

Moral of the story: if copying lines of code make sure that all references to namespaces are also copied.

Comment: I have got the same error because of wrong set resource location in Source={x:Static l:MainResource.Select}}. The error message is rather misleading than pointing where error is :S

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the error for me. This error message is truly terrible for the situation considering that in the resources section each item needs an `x:Key="..."` attribute.

Comment: I had it because I removed a reference to diagnostic settings but still used the setting.

Answer (score 15):

I was getting the same exact error and it turned out to be something different for me.

I was binding to properties using a fully qualified syntax because I didn't have a target object in my binding.  However I was doing it with shorthand and that's apparently not allowed with fully qualified syntax.  I had something like this:

```
{Binding (cmn:ElementData.ID)}
```

I changed it to:

```
{Binding Path=(cmn:ElementData.ID)}
```

And boom, cryptic error gone and everything worked as expected.  Apparently VERY important to not use shorthand with this...

Thanks to [Andrew Stakhov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1098390/andrew-stakhov) at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560550/wpf-binding-casting-in-binding-path) link whose comment tipped me off to this.

Comment: Thank you, I had encountered this problem years ago but it stumped me once again... scrolling to your post suddenly fired the connections in my brain! Aaah, WPF is fun! :-s

Comment: Just hit the same thing.  Beware casting in XAML.  There be Dragons

Comment: I was getting some obscure ArgumentNullException with absolutely no information every time I selected an item in a ListBox and this turned out to be the issue. Madness.