# WPF Binding : Casting in binding path

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I've a binding where the `Path` is set to `Path=Item.Tag.caption`, but I need to cast `Item` to `IEDGE` first so I can access the `Tag` Property.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you doing this in code or in Xaml?

Comment: I need to do this in Xaml

Comment: @Aminouvic If `Item` is implementing `IEDGE` and `Tag` is a property, it should work like you've posted it. What error are you getting?

Comment: @DHN the problem is that during binding `Item` is of type `object`, then I am getting an error that `Tag` property not found for `object`

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The solution for the problem, finally, is to use following syntax:

```
Path=Item.(myNameSpace:IEdge.Tag).caption
```

The previous code cast `Item` to the type `IEdge` in order to access the `Tag` property.

In case of multiple nested casts the global pattern is :

```
Path=Obj1.(ns1:TypeObj1.Obj2).(ns2:TypeObj2.Obj3)...(nsN:TypeObjN.BindedProp)
```

As suggested in comments **Do not use shorthand binding syntax when using this solution. Ensure you actually use `Path=` otherwise it won't work!**

Comment: That does not work for me. The entire expression in brackets is treated like a property. Where did you find information about this? I searched like entire Internet and never found nothing like this except your answer here...

Comment: Okay, I made it work but still - where you found this information? It seems like some WPF under-the-hood undocumented black magic...

Comment: @Libor : Actually I found the solution on msdn [PropertyPath XAML Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451.aspx) using **Property partial qualification** see section **Single Property, Attached or Otherwise Type-Qualified**

Comment: Thanks, I have skimmed the page first time and overlooked this. This is very helpful, saved me from writing custom converter or subclassing.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20120814100526/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451.aspx for those of us in 2015 where the link that @Aminouvic posted no longer exists.

Comment: This is not going to work as a general casting principal for XAML. it only valid when an indexer is needed to be accessed, I tried it and the parser fails at runtime shouting that an indexer cannot be null over this. vs2015

Comment: Do not use shorthand binding syntax when using this solution. Ensure you actually use Path= otherwise it won't work.

Comment: what if I just want to cast. and not access property like just `Item.(myNameSpace:IEdge)`? this fails it wants me to access property of `IEdge` but I just wanted to cast `Item` to `IEdge`?

Comment: Just to reiterate on Andrew Stakhov's point: you absolutely NEED to include the explicit Path= notation or this won't work.

Comment: Does this work for generic types? I'm getting the error `System.Xaml.XamlParseException : Type reference cannot find type named '{clr-namespace:presentation;assembly=presentation, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null}MyGenericClass.MyNestedClass'.`

Comment: What is `shorthand binding syntax`?

Comment: year 2022. here is the updated link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/propertypath-xaml-syntax?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#single-property-attached-or-otherwise-type-qualified