# WPF Casting in Binding Path

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, casting

This is a similar problem to [WPF Binding : Casting in binding path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16560550/31326), where I need to cast an object in a XAML binding statement.  But I can't seem to understand how to craft the binding in my particular case.

The answer to that question references [PropertyPath XAML Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451.aspx), and the relevant section is (I believe) `Single Property, Attached or Otherwise Type-Qualified`.

In my case, in my main View Model I have a dictionary that maps strings to objects that implement a base interface:

```
Dictionary<string, IFlintStone> FlintStones { get; set;}

public interface IFlintStone { Walk, Talk etc}
public class FlintStone : IFlintStone { .. }
```

However I also have these additional objects and interfaces which subclass the base object:

```
public interface IFred : IFlintStone { Eat, Drink, Yell etc }
public interface IWilma : IFlintStone { Wash, Clean, Cook etc }

public class Fred : FlintStone, IFred {..}
public class Wilma : FlintStone, IWilma {..}
```

And eventually I populate my dictionary like:

```
FlintStones["Fred"] = new Fred();
FlintStones["Wilma"] = new Wilma();
```

Now, in my XAML I have a user control for rendering a `Fred` object, and another one for rendering a `Wilma` object.  I can set the data context of these user controls doing something like:

```
<FredControl DataContext="{Binding Path=FlintStones[Fred]}" />
<WilmaControl DataContext="{Binding Path=FlintStones[Wilma]}" />
```

However my understanding is that this will only expose the `IFlintStone` components of those objects to their respective user controls.  But I want to expose `IFred` to the `<FredControl>` and `IWilma` to the `<WilmaControl>`

Is this possible and what would the binding syntax be in this case?

Using ideas from the links I referenced above, I have tried things like:

```
<FredControl DataContext="{Binding path=(myns:Fred.FlintStones[Fred])}" />
```

and

```
<FredControl DataContext="{Binding path=(myns:Fred).FlintStones[Fred]}" />
```

(Where `myns` is an xaml namespace definition pointing to the `Fred` object in the assembly.)

But the program either crashes and burns on start, or it complains that it can't find `Fred` as a property of the current data context.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a working version of my interpretation of your issue:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication22.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication22"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FlintStones[Fred].FlintStone}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FlintStones[Fred].(local:Fred.Yell)}" />
        <local:FredControl DataContext="{Binding Path=FlintStones[Fred]}" />
        <TextBlock />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FlintStones[Wilma].FlintStone}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FlintStones[Wilma].(local:Wilma.Clean)}" />
        <local:WilmaControl DataContext="{Binding Path=FlintStones[Wilma]}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WpfApplication22
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public Dictionary<string, IFlintStone> FlintStones { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            FlintStones = new Dictionary<string, IFlintStone>();
            FlintStones["Fred"] = new Fred();
            FlintStones["Wilma"] = new Wilma();

            this.DataContext = this;
        }
    }

    public interface IFlintStone
    {
        string FlintStone { get; set; }
    }
    public interface IFred : IFlintStone
    {
        string Yell { get; set; }
    }
    public interface IWilma : IFlintStone
    {
        string Clean { get; set; }
    }

    public class Fred : IFred
    {
        public string FlintStone { get; set; }
        public string Yell { get; set; }

        public Fred()
        {
            FlintStone = "Fred Flintstone";
            Yell = "Yabba Dabba Doo";
        }
    }

    public class Wilma : IWilma
    {
        public string FlintStone { get; set; }
        public string Clean { get; set; }

        public Wilma()
        {
            FlintStone = "Wilma Flintstone";
            Clean = "Mammoth Dish Washer";
        }
    }
}
```

FredControl.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication22.FredControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel Background="Beige">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FlintStone}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Yell}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

WilmaControl.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication22.WilmaControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel Background="AntiqueWhite">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FlintStone}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Clean}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

FredControl.xaml.cs and WilmaControl.xaml.cs are unmodified (just InitializeComponent(); in the constructors).

And a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This is a really clear example of complex binding syntax. I wonder if IntelliSense works as you're typing it out?

Comment: The missing }'s was an over site .. I really don't have classes called Fred and Wilma

Comment: @PeterM - I'll remove that part from the answer. I guess I should've realized that. Of course you would know the binding syntax.

Comment: It looks like your example is exactly what I mean.  It also looks like that I made an unwarranted assumption that the UserControls would only see the base interface (`IFlintStone`) instead of the most expansive interfaces (`IFred` and `IWilma`).  The casting in the additional texblocks of the main windows isn't something I need to do, but thanks for that syntax!

Comment: OK .. now I see where the casting fits in .. in the class definition of the user control itself!

Comment: @RobPerkins - Unfortunately, no... it doesn't. You can add d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MainWindow}" to the MainWindow.xaml but that will only get you intellisense to the dictionary (FlintStones), once you index into it then intellisense dies --> Path=FlintStones[intellisense just quit working].