# Access property of content within button-style

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, controltemplate

I'm trying to create a `ControlTemplate` for a button and bind the `CommandParameter` to some property of the buttons `Content`.

This currently looks something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyleKey" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="controls:ButtonHelper.CornerRadius" Value="3"/>
    // stuck here
    <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding ((SomeDataClass)Content).Id}" /> 
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            // ...
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

which is called

```
<Button Command="{Binding SetActive}" Content="{Binding SomeDataObject}" Style="{DynamicResource MyStyleKey}" />
```

Normally I would set the `CommandParameter` directly

```
<Button Command="{Binding SetActive}" CommandParameter="{Binding SomeDataObject.Id}" Content="{Binding SomeDataObject}" Style="{DynamicResource MyStyleKey}" />
```

My understanding of templating is to not repeat yourself. 
As of the `Id`-property is part of the buttons `Content`, passing it to the template as `CommandParameter` makes totally sense.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, at least to me.

Comment: @FarhanAnam: How to access the property `Id` of the buttons bound `Content`-property to be passed to the `CommandParameter`

Comment: The last two lines of your question confused me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [relative source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Content.Id, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"/>
```

Comment: This is working. Thanks. 
Any chance to have intellisense enabled when typing `Content.` or is what is described on SO [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560550/wpf-binding-casting-in-binding-path) the only way?

Comment: @KingKerosin: the solution you referred won't work for this binding expression.

Comment: using `{Binding Content.(someNameSpace:SomeDataClass.Id), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self} }` is working. Giving me intellisense at designtime and correct binding at runtime. Why should it not?

Comment: @KingKerosin: I must be more clear. Intellisense doesn't work, binding is OK. I'm on VS 2015.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Of course there is no intellisense when typing `Content.`, but `Content.(someNameSpace.SomeDataClass.` will provide `Id` via intellisense.
Is there any other way, e.g. setting `d:???` somewhere to have intellisense at designtime?