# How to cast in XAML to access sub-class properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

In my project I have a list of `Units` which is being used as the source of data for a DataGrid. The `Units` type has two types of subclasses, `AUnits` and `BUnits`. Each `Unit` in the list is either an `AUnit` or a`BUnit`. My issue is when I try to bind to a property specific to one of the subclass unit types, XAML doesn't see it and I just get back 0's. Normally, if this was being done in C# I would just cast it and access the property, but  I am not able to do that at this point in my code. The bindings are being created in C# like this:

```
 dgtc.Header = Properties.Resources.MaxPressure;
 dgtc.MinWidth = 25;
 dgtc.Width = Properties.Settings.Default.MaxPressureColumnWidth;
 dgtc.IsReadOnly = true;
 dgtc.Binding = new Binding("Unit.MaxDepthRelativeToEntry")
 {
     Converter = new DistanceUnitsConverter()
 };
```

Where dgtc is a DataGridTextColumn. Unit.MaxDepthRelativeToEntry comes through as 0 because it is a property on the subclass of an `AUnit`, so XAML thinks I am trying to access an non-existent property.

I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560550/wpf-binding-casting-in-binding-path) and so far I have tried some of the following syntaxes:

```
dgtc.Binding = new Binding("AUnit.MaxDepthRelativeToEntry")
dgtc.Binding = new Binding("Unit(MyNameSpace:AUnit).MaxDepthRelativeToEntry")
dgtc.Binding = new Binding("Unit(MyNameSpace:AUnit.MaxDepthRelativeToEntry)")
```

and was not able to get any of those to work. I have also tried doing this through a converter, but the issue is, I don't have the list of units available to me when I am constructing the DataGrid/ setting up the bindings/etc. so I am not able to grab the property out of the instance and return it. Does anyone know of any way that I can, preferably in XAML, get to the properties of a subclass type of the type I am binding to?

Edit:

My DataGrid has the following XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="JobListView"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              ItemsSource="{Binding UnitStatusCollection, Mode=TwoWay}"
              CanUserDeleteRows="False"
              Style="{StaticResource JobGridViewStyle}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding JobsListViewSelectedUnitInfo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              Utility:DataGridColumnsBehavior.BindableColumns="{Binding DataGridColumns}"
              ContextMenu="{StaticResource ListViewContextMenu}"
              Margin="10,5,10,2"
              Grid.Row="2"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              SelectionUnit="FullRow"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
              RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowStyle}"
              CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}"
              AlternationCount="2"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
              CanUserResizeRows="False"
              HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#d6d6d6"
              VerticalGridLinesBrush="#d6d6d6"
              Background="#EAEAEA"
              >
```

The `ItemsSource` is set to the `UnitStatusCollection` which is an `ObservableCollection` of a class called `UnitInfo` which holds a `Unit` and a `UnitStatus`. I need to access the property `MaxDepthRelativeToEntry` in `Unit` of `UnitInfo`. But I need to be able to see `Unit` as `AUnit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are binding to a list of `Unit` objects, then the `DataContext` for your  `DataGridTextColumn` should be the `AUnit` or `BUnit` object itself, so your binding path should just be `new Binding("MaxDepthRelativeToEntry")`.

You might get some kind of runtime warning for properties that only exist on one SubClass but not others, but it shouldn't throw an exception.

Here's a quick code sample to give an example :

XAML :

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgTest" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="A" Binding="{Binding A}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="B" Binding="{Binding B}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="C" Binding="{Binding C}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Code-Behind :

```
var test = new List<ClassA>();
test.Add(new ClassB() { A = "A", B = "B" });
test.Add(new ClassC() { A = "A", C = "C" });
dgTest.ItemsSource = test;
```

where the classes are defined as

```
public class ClassA
{
    public string A { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public string B { get; set; }
}

public class ClassC : ClassA
{
    public string C { get; set; }
}
```

Output :

[image]

It also works the exact same way if I write the binding in code-behind instead of in XAML :

```
colB.Binding = new Binding("B")
```

Comment: I neglected to mention that there is a wrapper class around my Units, and that my ItemsSource is set in XAML like so: `ItemsSource="{Binding UnitStatusCollection, Mode=TwoWay}"`. Should I just be able to do something like: `dgtc.Binding = new Binding("UnitInfo.AUnit.MaxDepthRelativeToEntry")`, if UnitInfo is the wrapper class? I'll update the question as well

Comment: @KSF My answer would not change, although you'd have to add one more property to the binding path. For example, if you were binding to a collection of `UnitInfo` objects, and each object had a `Unit` property which could be either of type `AUnit` or `BUnit`, then your binding would just be `{Binding Unit.MaxDepthRelativeToEntry}` or `new Binding("Unit.MaxDepthRelativeToEntry")`. The text in the string should match whatever the normal c# would look like... if you could write `UnitStatusCollection[0].Unit.MaxDepthRelativeToEntry`, then your binding should be `Unit.MaxDepthRelativeToEntry`

Comment: @KSF If you're still unclear, please edit your question to include the structure of your object models. That is what defines what the binding path should be.