# Binding to a nested dictionary - how do I state that DictionaryEntry is a Collection/Dictionary?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, resourcedictionary

The context for this question is handling translations.  I've set up a `ResourceDictionary` which contains other `ResourceDictionary` instances with the relevant localized strings for different areas, in order to group them more easily.  Different translation item XAML files will be stored within different language code folders, however they're not necessary for the example below.

**TranslationItems1.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary ...>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Group1">
        <sys:String x:Key="Field1">Group1Field1</sys:String>
        <sys:String x:Key="Field2">Group1Field2</sys:String>
        <sys:String x:Key="Field3">Group1Field3 out</sys:String>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Group2">
        <sys:String x:Key="Field1">Group2Field1</sys:String>
        <sys:String x:Key="Field2">Group2Field2</sys:String>
        <sys:String x:Key="Field3">Group2Field3 out</sys:String>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

For parts where I want to use these translations, I set the `DataContext` and bind accordingly.

**UserControl1.xaml**

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Strings">
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="TranslationItems1.xaml" />
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Button>
        <Button.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu DataContext="{DynamicResource Strings}">
                <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=[Group1][Field1]}" />
                <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=[Group1][Field2]}" />
                <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=[Group1][Field3]}" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </Button.ContextMenu>
    </Button>
    <Button>
        <Button.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu DataContext="{DynamicResource Strings}">
                <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=[Group2][Field1]}" />
                <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=[Group2][Field2]}" />
                <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=[Group2][Field3]}" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </Button.ContextMenu>
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```

This approach appears to work perfectly.  It builds and runs and my strings appear as expected.

IntelliSense however complains with error code `XLS0521`, and states `Type 'DictionaryEntry' is not a collection.` for the binding paths.  This error disappears on build but will reappear if I make any subsequent changes to the file.

Googling that error code gives me a whopping 10 results.  I'm assuming this error occurring is because it doesn't know that `Group1` and `Group2` are dictionaries, but I don't know how to explicitly state that they are via XAML.

How can I specify in XAML that `Group1` and `Group2` are dictionaries?

Comment: Think of the XAML designer as a cranky old man who does a good job, but sometimes mutters harmlessly about stuff that's not actually happening. Nevertheless, [it does look like you can do type casts in Binding paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16562937/424129).

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I can tell your link applies only to properties and not indexers.  I did try and experiment with various combinations of parentheses around the different parts of the path, but to no avail.

Comment: Indexers, right. Yeah, that syntax is not going to get you anywhere.

Comment: Does it like `{Binding Path=Item[Group1].Item[Field1]}` any better?

Comment: That gives the slightly different error, `XLS0432`, `The property 'Item' was not found in type 'DictionaryEntry'.`.  It does build and run without problems though, just as before.

Comment: What version of VS are you using? In 2017 Pro, I don't get any errors or warnings from from your version or the `Item` version. But this is in a minimal test project.

Comment: VS2017 Professional.  It's also worth noting that in both cases, no error will show if there have been no edits made to the file since the last successful build.  Make a minor change to the file without building and the error will appear.

Comment: Hmm. I think you're may just have to write it off as XDesProc hearing voices.